# Optimizing a Combination Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm organizing a game tournament in a week. I began thinking about the best way to *mathematically* arrange the teams (so that they are really even, thus more competitive). So here's the data:

- 20 players in the event
- Each player is assigned a skill level (high number = skilled)
- 4 teams of 5 players each (although I'd prefer to build a algorithm that takes these as
  variables)
- I'm using a computer to solve the problem

So, I have 20 players. I'd like to generate 4 teams with 5 players each. To do this, I'd like to generate a list of all possible team combinations. To evaluate a team combination, I:

- Generate a combination of teams (a match)
- Sum the total skill for each team based off the players in that team
- Compare each team to each other, the highest difference between any two teams in the match is the "tolerance" level for that match. If the tolerance level is higher than a certain cap, the match is discarded

My current approach is to generate a base X number that is N digits long, where X is the number of teams I want, and N is the number of players. Then increment the base X number by 1, I'll get every possible team combination, and I can generate a list of matches that have low tolerance values.

The problem with this, as you probably know, is for 4 teams with 20 players, that's (4-1)^20 in base 3, which is 1E12 matches to check through. (This takes a long time on my computer). Is there a mathematical way to simplify this calculation to be doable in a short period of time?

By current method also allows for the possibility of uneven players spread across the number of teams, which is preferable. If this can't be present with a highly performant algorithm, then it's okay not to use it.

Comment: If you want to exploit mathematical-structure to beat brute-force, then you need to formulate it more formally. A skill-level is not a math-term (binary, integer, float, bounded or not, nonnegative...). Usually one has a cost-function to optimize, but that's hard to read out here as you seem to use (random? partial?) match/tournament-"simulations" which is not easily transformed to the usual discrete-opt approaches. The whole discard-thing is also unclear to me. Your calculation misses out (some) symmetry, but symmetry is not always easy to break.

Answer (score 1):

Try following approach:

- For teams 1 to 4: Take the strongest player from the remaining
- The the same in another direction: from 4 to 1
- Again 1 to 4
- Again 4 to 1
- In the last round use random

This works well when player skills are distributed more or less evenly. If not, then the probability of bigger differences between teams is higher.